# How to setup jenkins in a ubuntu 12.04 machine?

Tags: 12.04, jenkins

I have a machine in production which is running Ubuntu 12.04. I need to setup Jenkins on it. I was trying to follow this tutorial -

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-jenkins-on-ubuntu-12-04

But I am not able to make it work since the first line which I am trying to execute it's not working at all -

```
wget -q -O - https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

This line just hangs and it doesn't do anything. It makes me think that there is a firewall and we cannot access any outside link. Is there any way to confirm my theory?

So now is there any other way by which I can setup jenkins in my production machine cleanly?

Any step by step guidance will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:-**

This is what I got when I ran wget -

```
david@machineA:~$ wget https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key
--2015-03-30 13:21:20--  https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key
Resolving jenkins-ci.org... 199.193.196.24
Connecting to jenkins-ci.org|199.193.196.24|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-03-30 13:21:44--  (try: 2)  https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key
Connecting to jenkins-ci.org|199.193.196.24|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-03-30 13:22:07--  (try: 3)  https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key
Connecting to jenkins-ci.org|199.193.196.24|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2015-03-30 13:22:31--  (try: 4)  https://jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key
Connecting to jenkins-ci.org|199.193.196.24|:443...
```

Comment: @Helio I have updated the question with the output. It is just retrying every time so now I am pretty much sure it is because of firewall issue.

Comment: @Helio Networking team will not open the firewall for this issue for sure so I need to find some other way around. What is there in the file. I cannot open it for some reason.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the late reply, I was busy. Here you're a answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a ssh tunnel.

- Run in the server `ssh -f user@home_computer -L 80:pkg.jenkins-ci.org:80 -N`
- Add this line to `/etc/hosts` file:

  ```
  127.0.0.1 pkg.jenkins-ci.org
  ```
- Follow the installation guide.

Hackish, but I think that's what you are looking for.